# How to change the table row data according to dropdown values in Svelte-Typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte, storybook, gridstack

I have a table widget that is a grid stack item. The table is made as a component using svelte. Data for the dropdown item and table content is passed to this component from another typescript file(using storybook stories file for doing this). Initially, the dropdown items and then table data are drawn. I want to change the table row data when the dropdown item is changed. [Image for table widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8m8C.png)

The code for dropdowns and table data is shown below

```
    <script lang="ts">
let selected

// passed from a stories.ts file as JSON string
export let dropdownitems: any
export let tableData 

const handlechange = (item) => {

// expected code for changing table row content
}
<script>

<div class="content">
    <div class="select">
        <select bind:value={selected} on:change={() => handlechange(selected)}>
            {#each JSON.parse(dropdownitems) as item}
                <option value={item.id}>
                    {item.name}
                </option>
            {/each}
        </select>
    </div>

    <table>
        <tr style="background:{color}">
            {#each tableData[0].title as item}
                <th>{item.label}</th>
            {/each}
        </tr>
        {#each tableData[0].content as data}
            <tr style="background:{data.color}">
                {#each data.rowcont as datacont}
                    <td>{datacont}</td>
                {/each}
            </tr>
        {/each}
    </table>
</div>
```

Sample tableData object

```
tableData =  [
                    {
                        title: [{ label: 'Subgroup' }, { label: '# of Students' }, { label: '% of 
                                 population' }],
                        content: [
                            { color: '#e8f0f6', rowcont: ['504', '3732', '5.67'] },
                            { color: '#fff', rowcont: ['ELL', '4164', '6.32'] },
                            { color: '#e8f0f6', rowcont: ['ESE', '14768', '22.48'] },
                            { color: '#fff', rowcont: ['FRL', '32776', '49.75'] },
                        ],
                    },
                ],

DropdownItems =  [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'Calculate based on incident location'
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Calculate data based on current enrollment'
                },

            ],
```

Data want to show in table row when selecting the second item in dropdown

```
 Content =[ 
            {
                id: 0,
                data: [
                    { color: '#e8f0f6', rowcont: ['434', '3732', '5.67'] },
                    { color: '#fff', rowcont: ['ELL', '4164', '6.32'] },
                    { color: '#e8f0f6', rowcont: ['ESE', '14768', '22.48'] },
                    { color: '#fff', rowcont: ['FRL', '32776', '49.75'] },]
            },
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your desired API is but I'm assuming that you want to tell the parent/component user that it should update the data. I also don't know how your `stories.ts` looks like, but I'm assuming that you manually instantiate the Svelte component roughly like this:

```js
const instance = new Grid({ target: .., props: { dropdownitems: ..., data: ...}});
```

If yes, then you could dispatch a custom event from your component like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

let selected

// passed from a stories.ts file as JSON string
export let dropdownitems: any
export let tableData 

const handlechange = (item) => {
  // ...
  dispatch("select", item);
}
<script>
```

Then you could listen to that event on that component like this in your `stories.ts`:

```js
instance.$on("select", (evt) => {
  // evt.detail contains selection
  const newData = getNewDataSomehow(evt.detail);
  instance.$set({ data: newData });
});
```

See the Svelte docs for more on the imperative component API: https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api